# Is there a way to integrate Geany to Github? How it's done?

Tags: github, geany, geany-plugin

Their documentation seems to be lacking information on this. At [geany-plugins](https://github.com/geany/geany-plugins) I see GitChangebar, but I failed to find instructions.

Are there any ways of managing commits from geany?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plugin [GeanyVC](https://plugins.geany.org/geanyvc.html) to commit and do some more basic tasks on your code. GitChangebar is only able to show you changes done compared with current HEAD of your working copy. Currently -- Feb 2016 -- there is no official plugin available to push/pull or do branch management.

GeanyVC and GitChangebar is a good addition for command line you could use via VTE at bottom of Geany's window.